# How to download a specific file(csv) using a php script

Tags: php, csv, download

im generating a daily report from a php script, it is residing in a folder as follows

```
report_2015_02_15.csv
report_2015_02_16.csv
report_2015_02_17.csv
report_2015_02_18.csv
report_2015_02_19.csv
```

And im sending my users an email with link to download, once they click the download link the download script triggers and prepares the download. It currently gets all the files into an array sorts it and finds the latest for the download,

this method has a flow in it where, even when you go to a email that is 2 weeks older and clicks the download link, it gives you the latest report instead of giving the two weeks older report.

**so can anybody tell me a way to send the download link in my email with a relationship to its corresponding file?**

email script

```
$down_link = Config_Reader::readProjectConfig('tad')->base_url.'CSVDownload.php;

$mail = new Zend_Mail ();
$sentFromEmail = $config->sentFromrec;
$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail ( '-f' . $sentFromEmail );
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport ( $tr );
$mail->setReturnPath($sentFromEmail);
$mail->setFrom ( $sentFromEmail, 'Reporting' );

$email_body = "Hi,<br /><br />Download the weekly details of adtracker projects, by clicking the link below.
<br /> <a href=".$down_link.">Report</a><br /><br />Thank You.";

$mail->setBodyHtml ( $email_body );
$mail->addTo ( $weeklyReportRec);
$mail->setSubject ( "Report" );

try {
        $mail->send ();
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo "Mail sending failed.\n";
    }
```

download script

```
$basePath = "$download/dailyReport/";
$csvFiles = glob($basePath."/*.csv");
if(count($csvFiles)){
    array_multisort($csvFiles, SORT_DESC);
    $csvFile = $csvFiles[0];
}else{
    exit("Server error!");
}

$h = fopen($csvFile, "r");
$contents = fread($h, filesize($csvFile));
```

Comment: Add a parameter to the URL that contains the date of the report, and use that in the download script instead of just returning the latest one.

Comment: i used it.. people said its not safe!!! that could make a injection attack to my server

Comment: Check the format of the parameter, make sure it's just the date, nothing else.

Comment: yeah i understand, u mean to just to put the date and math filename with the same date...

Comment: thanks for all you reply.. im working on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query parameter indicating the report date on the download link. .../CSCDownload.php?date=2015/02/17

This will allow you to select the respective report from the available list.

Comment: i used it.. people said its not safe!!! that could make a injection attack to my server

Comment: You are not storing the information sent in query params or storing it anywhere. You are merely using it to resolve the report. So I don't see how that could lead to an injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use somthing like that as download script. I made just minum changes to get it work:

```
$date = $_GET['date'];
$basePath = "$download/dailyReport/";
$csvFiles = glob($basePath."/*.csv");

$file = $basePath . 'report_' . $date . '.csv';
$found = false;

foreach($csvFiles as $csvFile){
    if($file === $csvFile){
        $found = $csvFile;
        // You have found the file, so you can stop searching
        break;
    }
}
if(false === $found){
    exit("Server error!");
}

$h = fopen($found, "r");
$contents = fread($h, filesize($found));
```

Now you can call you script in your browser with "example.com/getcsvfile.php?date=2015_02_15" without worrying about injection, because you check if the file is one of the csv files.